# ffmpeg, audio tracks, and QuickTime player

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, h265

I tried to copy all streams (video, audio, subtitle) and add a tag with the following command in order to play the files using QuickTime player:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -tag:v hvc1 -acodec copy -scodec copy -map 0 out.mp4
```

The resulting file does open with QuickTime player, and the video/subtitles play fine, but the two audio tracks (E-AC3 in English and German) from the input file cannot be selected (`View → Languages → None`) and are in fact merged into each other while playing the video, even though both tracks are shown separately in `Inspector → Audio Details` and VLC handles them correctly. Is this a bug in QuickTime player, or would I need to add another option for QuickTime?

I experimented with various mapping options, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map:v:0 0:v:0 -tag:v hvc1 -c:v:0 copy -map:a:0 0:a:0 -c:a:0 copy -map:a:1 0:a:1 -c:a:1 copy out.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:1 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -map 0:2 -metadata:s:a:1 language=deu -c copy -tag:v hvc1 out.mp4
```

without success.

Comment: Try adding `-disposition:a:1 0` so that the default audio track is only the first one.

Comment: That did the trick – thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alain1A45 posted the correct answer as a comment, the following command creates an output file with working audio tracks for QuickTime player:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -tag:v hvc1 -acodec copy -scodec copy -map 0 -disposition:a:1 0 out.mp4
```